# MAUI app crashing after adding firebase crashlytics

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, maui, crashlytics

I followed the instructions in
https://cedricgabrang.medium.com/firebase-push-notifications-in-net-maui-android-32c808844d7e

But getting this error when app launching.(I'm targeting only android platform other removed).[image]

> Java.Lang.RuntimeException: 'Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The Crashlytics build ID is missing. This occurs when Crashlytics tooling is absent from your app's build configuration. Please review Crashlytics onboarding instructions and ensure you have a valid Crashlytics account.'

Comment: What instructions did you follow to add the package? You likely didn’t change the build configuration for the json file you added

Comment: package name of app which is basically application_id in csproject,  I kept same everywhere fcm, manifest.. etc.

Comment: when i comment it, it works.

 builder
     .UseMauiApp<App>()
     //.RegisterFirebaseServices() //<--problem is here
     .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>

Comment: Share the code of your Csproj file, the issue is in there

Comment: ^ did you get my message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this issue with following way:

Go to> Platform>Android>Resources>Values  Now here I added a file "strings.xml"   which is having code:

```
<resources>
<string name="default_notification_channel_id">ur_package_name.general</string>
</resources>
```

Now Important thing to do is:

Right click on string.xml file, and click on 'properties' now you will see a small window where you need to set 'Build Action' as 'Android Resource'.

It working fine for me now, sorry for late answer.

Comment: I was doing a code review of the Crashlytics implementation that didn't work, and with your phrase "set 'Build Action' as 'Android Resource'.", you solved my problems. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

If you using dotnet 8 you can config like me, in file project.csproj, this work for me:

```
<!--Begin:  Android-->
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net8.0-android'">
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Core" Version="1.12.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Collection" Version="1.4.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Collection.Ktx" Version="1.4.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Activity.Ktx" Version="1.8.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Browser" Version="1.7.0.2" />
    <GoogleServicesJson Include="Platforms\Android\google-services.json" />
</ItemGroup>
<!--End: Anroid-->
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Plugin.Firebase" Version="2.0.12" />
    <PackageReference Include="Plugin.Firebase.Crashlytics" Version="2.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Plugin.Firebase.CloudMessaging" Version="2.0.4" />
</ItemGroup>
```